# How to use the same variable in different scenes in AS3 Flash CS6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, scene

I have this`var num:Number;` in Scene 1.
I want to use it in the Scene 2 but I have no idea how to do it.

Sorry I am a newb and I have no idea how to look at the documentation corrrectly.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions would be to declare a class that would contain a static variable.

```
public class StaticVars {
    public static var num:Number=0;
    public function StaticVars() {}
}
```

Then you address it from anywhere using `StaticVars.num`. You can fit as many variables in a single class like this as you need to.

Comment: you don't need the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedObject.

in Scene 1;

```
var soScene1= SharedObject.getLocal("nums");
soScene1.data.num = num;
```

in Scene 2;

```
var soScene2= SharedObject.getLocal("nums");
var num2 = soScene2.data.num;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html